# What happens is a node receives a message while it's in the middle of a callback?

Tags: ros, queue, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm thinking of having a node send a message to another node as part of a callback function. It should receive a message from another node at about this time as well, before it finishes the callback function. What will ROS do in this case? Will the node pause the first callback function in order to execute the second, or will it finish executing the first callback before executing the callback function for the message it just received?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10720/what-happens-is-a-node-receives-a-message-while-it%27s-in-the-middle-of-a-callback?/) by [xeronia](https://answers.ros.org/users/738/xeronia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

callbacks will only be called from ros::spin(Once) or by manually calling the callback-queues to be processed.

Unless you use some kind of threading the function will finish and the other callback will be called in the next loop.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning has a good overview of roscpp's threading options.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1